# scp, where did my files go?

Tags: ssh, scp

I logged in with ssh, into a pc in our lab. I would like to copy a .txt from there, to my laptop in home. So I did:

```
root@hostname:/home/gsamaras/konstantis/cholesky# scp gsamaras@hostname.gr:konstantis/cholesky/o_755.txt /
o_755.txt                                     100%   23KB  22.6KB/s   00:00    
root@hostname:/home/gsamaras/konstantis/cholesky# scp gsamaras@hostname.gr:konstantis/cholesky/o_755.txt /home/gsamaras
o_755.txt                                     100%   23KB  22.6KB/s   00:00
```

With both attempts, I couldn't locate the file. Where did it go? Moreover, now I think that two of them should exist and I do not want to leave any leftovers.

---

Here is what I checked:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ pwd
/home/gsamaras
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ls
Desktop           Music                                     Templates
Documents         Pictures                                  ubuntu_May_2015.zip
Downloads         Public                                    Videos
examples.desktop  skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$ ls /
bin    dev   initrd.img      lib64       mnt   root  srv  usr      vmlinuz.old
boot   etc   initrd.img.old  lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
cdrom  home  lib             media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
gsamaras@gsamaras:~$
```

Comment: One of them should be in `/o_755.txt` and the other in `/home/gsamaras/o_755.txt` ..check `find / -type f -name 'o_755.txt' `

Comment: `find` takes forever.  Check my edit @heemayl.

Comment: What happened was you were ssh'ed into `hostname`. Exit the ssh session to go back to your `gsamaras` machine and run the `scp` command again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note what you're trying to achieve with this `scp` command:

```
root@hostname:/home/gsamaras/konstantis/cholesky#
```

You are `root` on machine named `hostname`

```
scp gsamaras@hostname:konstantis/cholesky/o_755.txt /
```

o_755.txt

You are trying to `scp` a file from `hostname:konstantis/cholesky` as `gsamaras` to `/o_755.txt` *on the current machine*.

You then login to a machine named `gsamaras` and look for the file there.  It's not going to be on `gsamaras`.  Try looking for the file in `/` and `/home/gsamaras/` **on `hostname`** (the current machine).

In order to do what I think you want, you'd have to run the following `scp` command:

```
scp gsamaras@hostname:konstantis/cholesky/o_755.txt gsamaras@gsamaras:~/
```

Where `hostname` is the current machine.

Comment: Edited, I should have yanked the full address(es) immediately, but it escaped my attention. Cheers.